# How can I tell maven to war my javascript project from the root dir

Tags: javascript, eclipse, node.js, maven

Folks, I have yet to see a build method to war up a javascript project.

Currently the defacto method is to just shove it out to the docroot of your appserver which I find atrocious.

Given that my hello world node.js javascript project has at least 27,000 modules beneath the project root dir has made any attempt to operate the root dir impossible even inside eclipse due to the parsing and processing and preprocessing that managing and handling the project has to go thru.

I also find atrocious that GOOGLE is the goto corp (which humanity has bought into and sold out for) for all corps just because they are politically designed for totalitarianism and they got no chance of operating neuro or nano processing integrated to any internet unless they got super high speed abilities to process. Personally they need to change their platform to something faster than speed of light.

And the coding is outrageous..stuffing every concept into a dom node. Corporations are in for a big bottleneck surprise.

Regardless, I cannot create a maven project to traverse and bundle up my javascript node.js helloworld project due to the incompetent slowness of even attempting to manage this amount of dependencies required to operate such a project.

Is there a maven script available to leapfrog me to a packaged up war'd up helloworld project that I can copy to tomcat docroot ?

How do I build a node.js project for production packaging and deployment.

Answer (score 1):

well political aspects aside, Google would have been able to help you.

There are tutorials around (maven node.js archetype) like this one: http://blog.akquinet.de/2011/02/11/mavenizing-javascript-projects/

There are some available for Grunt: https://github.com/tarent/mvn-grunt-archetype
(as source of inspiration)

There are some maven tutorials around that will help you to create a basic war file: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html

From there it should be easy to add the files you need.

Maven is (unlike gradle) less of a scripting environment. It works via convention over configuration. So you need to search for maven plugins that do what you want to do if none of the default plugins do the job.
The most used plugins are found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html

There are also good tutorials on the maven website that help you getting started: http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html

I don't know much about node.js - they may have also their own way of packaging and deploying applications. It seems a little weird to create a node.js war file, since node.js runs javascript on the server I don't see why one would package that in a war file.

If 27000 is too much to cope with the way to go is always the same: command and conquer. split it into smaller parts. Or did you refer to the node.js modules? Because you will not need all of them to run an application.